# Which server-side session management is active & popular now?

Tags: flask, flask-session

[Flask-Session](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) is giving me a 404 error. Can't find documentation for it.

However I can still install it using:

```
pip3 install flask-session
```

[Flask-KVSession](https://github.com/mbr/flask-kvsession/) is no longer maintained. Last commit was 5 years ago.

[Flask-Sessionstore](https://github.com/mcrowson/flask-sessionstore) is no longer maintained either. Last commit was 3 years ago.

Comment: Link to [flask-session documentation](https://flasksession.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) from their [github repo](https://github.com/fengsp/flask-session) in the description of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190529075734/https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Session/) this is just a snapshot of the website using Wayback machine